# (!potential spoilers for people who haven't played) In the Witness, how do I solve this puzzle?

Tags: the-witness

[image: shipwreck puzzle]

I'm terrified to Google this and I would appreciate if anyone could answer this as gingerly and spoiler-free as possible because I'm not very far in the game and I'd like to experience all of the puzzles on my own. I take exception with this particular quandary because I've spent the last 30 minutes feathering the thumbstick ever-so-slightly in every direction, trying to get this thing to activate, and it won't do it.

I'm getting varying degrees of sparks when I click in the circle, but I can't seem to line it up properly. Is there a different (maybe higher?) perspective that I am supposed to activate it from? Does the circle on the right-hand side need to be fully closed (ie: no chunk cut out in the middle)? Or is it more important that the circle is as circular as possible? The amount of sparks on the various attempts seems to indicate that the latter is more important, but about 300 attempts haven't sealed the deal, and I'm starting to question my sanity :p

Thanks in advance for your help :) The game is really great so far!! I was grinning like a buffoon when I discovered the first symbol for the black obelisks; I thought the game consisted entirely of the little panel puzzles.

Comment: Ack, sorry for the duplicate; like I said, I was pretty terrified to google it for fear of accidentally spoiling anything for myself. To the answerer, @Chris, I'll take your advice and avoid the rest of your answer until I've progressed to a point where I'm no longer worried about spoilers. Thanks for the encouragement! I'll accept your answer once I've hit that point and I can read the entire thing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this isn't the answer you're looking for, but I'd recommend coming back to this later. There are other environmental puzzles in other parts of the island that, once you have found them, the answer to this one will be obvious.

Really. I'd encourage you to stop reading now. The game is more fun the more puzzles you solve on your own.

But if you insist, here's my gingerly worded hint.

> It looks like a piece of the circle is missing. Can you find a way to fill it in?

Comment: I don't think it's obvious at all.  This one took me a while to figure out.